How to use different plists for different schemes in xcode
Is there a simple way to have different plists for different schemes? I use xcode only rarely for building Flutter apps.
There are two schemes in the project 'uat' and 'prod'. I see there are two folders config/uat and config/prod and there are files GoogleService-Info.plist in both of them.
I need different config for Facebook auth, so is it possible to create new plists in each folder, let's say Facebook-Info.plist and put values to these files?
Will it work this way? Or do I need to set something else? Somehow bind the file with the scheme. The version of Xcode is 15.2.


Do you really need two Facebook-Info.plist files? AFAIK, facebook authentication only needs a few fields like FacebookAppID, FacebookClientToken, etc, right?

Yes, Facebook auth need two values at the moment (app id and client token), but I need different values for uat and for prod. As all examples are based on placing these values to plist, I'd like to have two plists (one for each scheme). If there are more values for Facebook (or any other service), I can simply add new values to respective file if it needs to be different for each scheme.

If that's the case, I would recommend a single plist file with different xcconfig files.

Create xcconfig file that represents the desired environments, in this scenario are UAT and PRODUCTION


File -> New -> Configuration Settings File

Then define these variables in UAT and PRODUCTION xcconfig files that were created above.
FACEBOOK_APP_ID          = xxx //<- your app id
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_TOKEN    = yyy //<- your app token



In the plist file, create the key-value pairs like this:




You also need to create a new configuration via the below step. Do it the same with the production environment, or you can use directly Release by default.





Now that you're able to switch between different environments. The final step is to configure the scheme, Run or Archive with matched build configurations.



So whenever you want to extend, you only need to create a new xcconfig file instead of duplicating another scheme.

I use xcode for building Flutter apps (developed either in Android Studio od IntellJ Idea). This IDE then calls xcode to build iOS app. I only specify flavor which Flutter converts to xcode scheme. So I'm not sure that creating xcconfigs is an option for me.
(https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors#creating-flavors-in-ios-and-macos)

I think it's quite related. Nothing stops you from creating a new scheme (it's step 2 and step 5 on the link above). i.e., Runner-uat and Runner-production, then you can assign desired configurations to each scheme. However, I think it's not necessary to create a new scheme.
